# How to bind HTML elements Navigated through WebBrowser control in c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have Navigated a local HTML file through WebBrowser control in c#. This HTML has one element with id: ToolName
I can set ToolName like this.

```
private void OnLoadCompleted (object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     HTMLDocument dom = 
     (HTMLDocument)this.Browser.Document;
     object ie = dom.getElementById("ToolName");
     if (ie != null)
     {
        var spanElement = ie as HTMLSpanElement;
        if (spanElement != null)
        {
           spanElement.innerText = "TestPage";
        }
     }
  }
```

But, Is there any way I can bind this ToolName from view Model rather than using `elementID` and `innerText`?

Comment: Why not add a ToolName variable to your model and render that in the span?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hassan. This is my HTML row for the ToolName.                                                      
  <tr>
               <td class="REPHEADERTOOLNAME">Tool Name: &nbsp;<span id = "ToolName">-----------------</span></td>
            </tr>    I can create the property ToolName in Model but how can I bind it to the span element. can you please explain.

Comment: <span id = "ToolName">@Model.ToolName</span>

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting it right.
Output:
  Report
Tool Name: @ModelData.ToolName
Serial Number: 11111111
This is what I am doing in ViewModel and HTML.
public WebBrowserViewModel ()
{
ModelData = new WebBrowserData();
ModelData.ToolName = "testTool";
}
ToolName is the property in Model class.
<tr>
<td class="REPHEADERTOOLNAME">Tool Name: &nbsp;<span id = "ToolName" >@ModelData.ToolName</span></td>
</tr>

Comment: Why I am not able to break line? As I press enter it add the comment.